# Need Counter Value in Muenchian grouping logic code

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have requirement to print the incremental value within a for-each (Muenchian grouping) function
which I have already used.
Please find the snippet code

```
    <xsl:template>
    <xsl:for-each select="./DocumentPayable/DocumentPayableLine[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Locationabc', ./Tax/TaxRateCode))]">
                <xsl:if test="(LineType/Code='AWT')">
                    <xsl:variable name="LocationCode" select="./Tax/TaxRateCode"/>  
                    <Rcrd>
                    <AddtlInf>/D1/<xsl:value-of select="(Tax/TaxRateCode)"/></AddtlInf>
                    </Rcrd>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected Output:

```
/D1/INDIA
/D2/USA
/D3/AFRICA
```

Based on number of tax rate codes the incremental value should be shown.

Please help.

Comment: Please, show a source XML document and the exact wanted output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a predicate and `position()` e.g.

```
        <xsl:for-each select="./DocumentPayable/DocumentPayableLine[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Locationabc', Tax/TaxRateCode))][LineType/Code='AWT']">                    
                <Rcrd>
                <AddtlInf>/D<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>/<xsl:value-of select="Tax/TaxRateCode"/></AddtlInf>
                </Rcrd>              
        </xsl:for-each>
```